# Trouble installing Cloudera

Tags: cloudera

When I tried running the:

```
sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

I got an error that said the following about half-way through the installation processes

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package cloudera-manager-server
```

I can't seem to find a solution anywhere, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a proxy problem, so never mind :)